# Como trocar dois nós não consecutivos em uma lista duplamente encadeada?

Tags: c

Eu precisava trocar dois nós consecutivos ou não numa lista duplamente encadeada, mas eu não consigo. Alguém pode me ajudar? Já até fiz no papel mas não executa. Qual o problema do código?

```
void swap(no_teste* A, no_teste* B) {

    no_teste* proximoA = A->prox;
    no_teste* anteriorB = B->ant;

    A->prox = B->prox;
    B->ant = A->ant;

    A->ant = anteriorB;
    anteriorB->prox = A;
    B->prox = proximoA;
    proximoA->ant = B;

}
```

Eu me perco com essa troca de ponteiros, se fosse lista simplesmente encadeada eu conseguiria. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Essas últimas eu tentei no papel mas não consegui nem usá-las:

```
void init(no_teste* aA, no_teste* A, no_teste* bA, no_teste* aB, no_teste* B, no_teste* bB) {
    aA = A->ant;
    bA = A->prox;
    aB = B->ant;
    bB = B->prox;
}

void Disconect_Geral_Node(no_teste* aA, no_teste* A, no_teste* bA) {

    aA->prox = NULL;
    A->ant = NULL;
    A->prox = NULL;
    bA->ant = NULL;

}

void Geral_Conect(no_teste* aA, no_teste* B, no_teste* bA) {
    aA->prox = B;
    B->ant = aA;
    B->prox = bA;
    bA->ant = B;
}
```

Comment: Trocar os ponteiros `prox` e `ant` ou trocar o conteúdo basta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu código as alterações ao `B->prox` e `A->ant` não estão corretas:

```
A->ant = anteriorB;
B->prox = proximoA;
```

Pois o anterior de `A` vai passar a ser o `B`, e o próximo de `B` vai passar a ser o `A`. Para além disso não precisa das variáveis temporárias se fizer as trocas na ordem correta.

Como primeira abordagem pode fazer assim:

```
void swap(no_teste* A, no_teste* B) {
    A->ant->prox = B;
    B->prox->ant = A;
    A->prox = B->prox;
    B->ant = A->ant;
    B->prox = A;
    A->ant = B;
}
```

Nesta versão de swap alterei primeiro anterior ao `A` e depois o próximo do `B` e por isso não foi necessário guardar valores em variáveis temporárias.

Esta solução não irá funcionar se a troca for no fim da lista ou no inicio da lista pois `A->ant` ou `B->prox` serão `NULL`, o que irá resultar num *segmentation fault*. Para resolver temos que testar o `NULL` antes de alterar:

```
void swap(no_teste* A, no_teste* B) {
    if (A->ant != NULL){
        A->ant->prox = B;
    }

    if (B->prox != NULL){
        B->prox->ant = A;
    }

    A->prox = B->prox;
    B->ant = A->ant;
    B->prox = A;
    A->ant = B;
}
```

Agora apesar de não dar erro a troca no inicio da lista também não irá ficar correta pois seria necessário alterar a cabeça da lista, algo que não contemplou no próprio cabeçalho da função:

```
void swap(no_teste** lista, no_teste* A, no_teste* B) {
    if (A->ant != NULL){
        A->ant->prox = B;
    }
    else {
        *lista = B; //se A->ant é NULL, A é a cabeça e B passa agora a ser a cabeça
    }

    if (B->prox != NULL){
        B->prox->ant = A;
    }

    A->prox = B->prox;
    B->ant = A->ant;
    B->prox = A;
    A->ant = B;
}
```

[Exemplo dos swaps no Ideone](https://ideone.com/1sHx5p)

Nos exemplos do ideone utilizei duas funções de mostrar para ser fácil de ver que tanto os ponteiros `ant` como `prox` estão corretos.

Também considerei que era uma lista duplamente ligada não circular.